# Android Opengl GLU.gluLookAt doesn't work

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGL and I can't figure out how to use gluLookAt. Below is my source -- Any help will be much appreciated.

```
   public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {       
       gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbientBuffer);                gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuseBuffer);              gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPositionBuffer);   
 gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);                                                   
gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);               
      gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);       

     gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);              
     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);           
     gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);           
     gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);           
     gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                    
     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);                 
     gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);            


    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 


    cube.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
}



public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, xrot, yrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, xrot, yrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

    //Check if the light flag has been set to enable/disable lighting
    if(light) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    } else {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    }

    //Check if the blend flag has been set to enable/disable blending
    if(blend) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);         //Turn Blending On ( NEW )
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   //Turn Depth Testing Off ( NEW )

    } else {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);        //Turn Blending On ( NEW )
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);    //Turn Depth Testing Off ( NEW )
    }

    //Drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, z);         //Move z units into the screen
    gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);          //Scale the Cube to 80 percent, otherwise it would be too large for the screen

    //Rotate around the axis based on the rotation matrix (rotation, x, y, z)
    gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
    gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y

    cube.draw(gl, filter);                  //Draw the Cube 



    //Change rotation factors
    xrot += xspeed;
    yrot += yspeed;
}


/**
 * If the surface changes, reset the view
 */
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I can see. One, since glulookat is defined as 
`gluLookAt   (    eyeX , eyeY , eyeZ , centerX , centerY , centerZ , upX , upY , upZ )`

Your call should be changed to be `GLU.gluLookAt(gl, xrot, yrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, xrot, yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);`

Notice the new up vector '0.0, 1.0, 0.0'. Basically says the y-axis is where you want 'up' to be.

Also, you seem to be using rotation values for the rest of the call. The first triplet should be the position of where you are looking, and the second vector should be a reference position, normally where your viewer is. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html

Second issue, if you call loadIdentity after a glulookat call, I am pretty sure since it is loading the identity matrix, you will loose the transform that glulookat performs. So try adding glulookat after you have placed your geometry.

Here is what I am basically saying in code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

//cleaned up the reset code
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     
gl.glLoadIdentity();                    
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    

//Check if the light flag has been set to enable/disable lighting
if(light) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
} else {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
}

//Check if the blend flag has been set to enable/disable blending
if(blend) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);         //Turn Blending On ( NEW )
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   //Turn Depth Testing Off ( NEW )

} else {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);        //Turn Blending On ( NEW )
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);    //Turn Depth Testing Off ( NEW )
}

//Drawing
gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, z);         //Move z units into the screen
gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);          //Scale the Cube to 80 percent, otherwise it would be too large for the screen

//Rotate around the axis based on the rotation matrix (rotation, x, y, z)
gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y

//change the perspective matrix to look at the rotating cube (0,0,z), from (0,0,0)
//with (0,1,0) as the up vector
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0.0f, 0.0, z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
cube.draw(gl, filter);                  //Draw the Cube 



//Change rotation factors
xrot += xspeed;
yrot += yspeed;


 }
```